# Transform matrix efficiently

Tags: python, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
matrix = [[3,2,3],
         [-6,7-9],
         [-6,5,-12]]
```

How can I create an array of the same size but with zeros using Python in the most efficient and short way without using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy one-liner:

```
zeros = [[0]*len(matrix[0]) for _ in range(len(matrix))]
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. The resulting list will suffer from this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: @JussiNurminen No it won't. That's the exact reason I used list comprehension instead of just doing `[[0]*len(matrix[0])]*len(matrix)`. That would cause the issue you linked.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry about that.